# Describe a chord shape?

Tags: guitar, notation

Is there a standard or compact way to describe a chord shape, using text?

For example, the D/C chord is:

> - 6th string: muted
> - 5th string: **3rd** finger on 3rd fret (C)
> - 4th string: open (D)
> - 3rd string: **1st** finger on 2nd fret (A)
> - 2nd string: **4th** finger on 3rd fret (D)
> - 1st string: **2nd** finger on 2nd fret (F#)

That's wordy, however.

I'm hoping for a compact alternative to a chord diagram, like this one:

[image]

from https://www.8notes.com/guitar_chord_chart/d_c-bass.asp

because I want to annotate a score, e.g. when the score asks for a D/B chord I want a reminder of how to finger that.

Something like`X-3-0-1-4-2` is a fairly suitable answer (for the D/C example above), but could it be better or is there a more standard way? Because this tells you the finger-number-sequence, but not the corresponding fret numbers or note names.

Comment: The fingering itself is not too important. With some chords, there's only one sensible way to finger, with others, there's options which depend on the player. String/fret is way more useful. Most of us will go automatically to a given name, and have, sometimes, several different voicings. Consider open D - 12 different fingerings, I think...  But, often, the actual shape/voicing will be left to the discretion of the player, in fairness. Unless you need a particular one, which could be portrayed by the dots on the staff.

Comment: @Tim I'm a learner/novice, and changing the fingering from D/C to D/B is non-trivial: so it was important to me! That said, would you (or is it standard to) annotate the fret-numbers then instead of the finger-numbers -- e.g. `X-3-0-2-3-2` for the D/C chord?

Comment: Similarly, explaining fingering is something that elementary *teachers* seem to spend time doing.

Comment: That way of expressing it is clear and concise. Unequivocal. After enough times, you'll figure out fingering for each, and also automatically go to the correct places to play the chord. Remember, a lot of us need to see a chord symbol and play it in time, while sightreading live. I don't think many players would do that successfully even with x-3-0-2-3-2, so it's an aid for learning rather than anything else, and will be disregarded later, one hopes!

Comment: Fingering is something I don't explain often. That's part and parcel of the student's homework: the mechanical part. To decide which fingering suits which chord best. And often there'll be at least two useful options to learn.

Comment: @Tim Yes I was trying to annotate a score I practice from. A "score" tends to have lyrics and chord names only, and a strum pattern ... and (if I take enough time to write it) a staff with the melody (note values and durations and how lyrics fit to the measures) ... I wanted to annotate (so I wouldn't forget, so I could practice) the fingering for this chord transition too, but [Guitar fretboard diagram generators](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/11508/49554) didn't have an easy answer; so I wondered whether there's some a text-based way to annotate. I guess you're saying "no".

Comment: I wouldn't bother. Merely learn the chord shapes, and alternatives, if needs be, knowing why certain strings are pressed on certain frets helps some people, so that when you see a chord symbol, your fingers go straight to the correct chord. If you're at the stage where you know only a few chords, find other songs with the same chords, and play through those as well. You'll find chords are often in 'families', so the same few crop up in many songs - especially if they're in that same key. If not, transpose them!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I've always notated in the text this:

> - 6th string: muted
> - 5th string: **3rd** finger on 3rd fret (C)
> - 4th string: open (D)
> - 3rd string: **1st** finger on 2nd fret (A)
> - 2nd string: **4th** finger on 3rd fret (D)
> - 1st string: **2nd** finger on 2nd fret (F#)

is this:

`x30232`

where 0 (zero) is open, x is muted and the numbers correspond to the fret number, not the finger number.

Comment: Should be x30232

Answer (score 2):

There's an example [here](https://www.heartwoodguitar.com/chords/kansas-dust-in-the-wind/):

[image]

---

That's pretty compact, and obvious how to read it -- for example, the C chord:

`32 1`
`x32010`

---

A naive attempt to write the above produced this result:

```
 32 1
x32010
```

... which introduced me to the fact that this site supports [meta-tag:jtab] -- for example this ...

`%X/X.3/3.2/2.0/0.1/1.0/0[C]`

... renders like this ...

```
%X/X.3/3.2/2.0/0.1/1.0/0[C]
```

... (so the "jtab" syntax is another semi-standard syntax, machine-readable for what that's worth).

Answer (score 1):

I can back "pro"-s answer. It's a bit unusual to write it like this, but it works.

I must note though, that TABs contain more info: bending, slide hammer on, vibrato (you can even put the rhythm there, though I have never seen a tab like that).

So, depending on your goal, the good old TAB system is the way if you want to put down in a lot more detail a guitar piece.

For example, bellow you can see hammer-on, slide, and a 1/4 bend (it's an often heard blues lick):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. To be clear I I think that [tablature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tablature#Guitar_tablature) (the good old TAB system) shows the notes (i.e. string plus fret) but not the fingering. Can you reference (add a hyperlink to) a nice example of a TAB to illustrate what you're saying?

Comment: I cannot really.  You have to see, hear solos, for exact timing and knowledge how to bend, hammer-on, pull-off. Bellow you can see hammer-on, slide, and a 1/4 bend. It's an often heard blues lick. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bznje_d3QT1AdWFxdFNpanE0bFU?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

What they usually do in music scoring is that they display chord shapes (like a neck diagram) with their notation at the begining of the score. This acts like a convention. Then they write the notation when needed in the core of the music.

Comment: I think you're saying they usually write e.g. `D/C` inside the core, and have chord diagrams to illustrate the various chord names before the start of (or otherwise outside) the score.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. This is usually how it's done.

Comment: It depends who the publishers are. Some often do, others never.

Comment: What I meant is: it seems to be the most adapted solution to your problem. You also have to keep in mind that people are going to read you. So you have to produce something they already know, or they might not understand what you meant!

Comment: The problem with neck diagrams is that they tend to be generic chord shapes.  For good voice leading, you may need inversions and positions up and down the neck.